# undefined method rails -- calling a controller method from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The error is undefined method 'get_image_url' for Item, even after declaring a helper method.

Although I don't see why something in the view should be explicitly enabled to call a controller method.

this is the model method

```
def item_url
   return self.image_url # simplified version for simplicities sake
end
```

and in the controller

```
def get_image_url
   Item.item_url
end
helper_method :get_image_url
```

in the view

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <img src="<%= item.get_image_url%>"></img>
<% end %>
```

I am not sure what to do about this, I feel like my design is not ideal and I need some feedback from more experienced developers. ah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're trying to call an instance method from an non-initiated object

The `item_url` should be a [class method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) if you're calling on a "naked" model, or should be initialized to call an instance method:

```
#Instance
def get_image_url
   @item = Item.find(1)
   @item.item_url
end

#Class
def get_image_url
   Item.item_url
end

def self.item_url
   item = find(1)
   item.image_url
end
```

The next problem you have is you're calling what you deem to be an instance method as a `helper`. The problem is you're referencing your model directly, and should be done through the model

---

**Fix**

There's no point calling the `get_image_url` method - you're just routing to a model method anyway. You should rename `item_url` to `get_image_url` in your model, and call it as an instance method from your view. Because your `clothing_item` object is an initialized version of your `Item` model, you'll be able to use an instance method on it no problem:

```
<% @clothing_items.each do |clothing_item| %>
  <img src="<%= clothing_item.get_image_url%>"></img>
<% end %>

#app/models/item.rb
def get_image_url
   image_url # simplified version for simplicities sake
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method like `get_image_url` on an object of class `Item`, Rails looks for the method definition inside the `Item` class definition in `item.rb`. But Rails isn't finding it there. Thus, Rails says the method is undefined.

Another issue is `Item.item_url`. This is calling a method on the `Item` class itself, not an object or objects of that class. Thus, you would need to define the method `item_url` in your `Item` model as a class method (as opposed to an instance method).

Here, though, I don't think you need to use class methods at all, if your goal is to display each item's image individually. You can just use your view file as is, and define  `get_image_url` in your model as an instance method.